# Azure: connect to VM using an Azure AD account (WAAD)

Tags: authentication, azure

How can I RDP to an Azure box using an account I created in Azure? I don't want to go down the route of syncing directories or anything. Just simply want to be able to create accounts in Azure that can be used to access Azure servers.

This is a basic centralised authentication model and I am sure I am just missing something. Surely Microsoft can't expect us to add a bunch of users and service accounts on EACH server we create and manage passwords etc as entirely separate entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cannot do this (without resorting to directory synchronisation). A Configuration Management tool such as SaltStack/Chef/Puppet seems a leaner fit than creating a traditional AD infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

By "Azure Box" I assume you mean an Azure VM running Windows. There's nothing "magical" about these VMs. If you want central user management instead of relying on local user accounts you need to add it to an Active Directory domain. And if you want sync between this Active Directory domain and the Azure Active Directory for your tenant, you need to set up Directory Sync.

Comment: Correct. Thanks for your clarification Trondh.